# How to set the linear layout width in a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a `LinearLayout` (let's call it **A**)that it's width set to `fill_parent`, this layout contains a bunch of another `LinearLayouts`(let's call them **B**), I want the screen only display *four* **B**'s so i assigned the `weight_sum` of **A** as `4` and assigned each one of **B**'s as `1`, now i want to add a `HorizontalScrollView` so that if i have like 6 layouts of **B** only four will be displayed and the other two will be scrolled. I build this `HorizontalScrollView` to contain the **A** layout(as the `HorizontalScrollView` should has only one direct child), now the fill_parent width i add to the layout **A** is ruined as it now obeys the `HorizontalScrollView` so the **B** layouts width is ruined also, take a look at the following figures:

-- *yellow* : the Whole Screen.

-- *green* : **A** Layout.

-- *red* : **B** Layout.

**The result I got:**

[image]

**The result i suppose to get:**

[image]

I'm tried to set the width of both `HorizontalScrollView` and the Layout **A** to `fill_parent` and/or `wrap_content` but nothing works with me.

My **XML** Code:

```
      <HorizontalScrollView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <LinearLayout 
                       android:id="@+id/A"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:orientation="horizontal"
                       android:weightSum="4" >

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/B1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
             <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/B2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/icon4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/ac_overlay"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:tag="normal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                  </LinearLayout>
                 </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: not really an answer to your question and probably will not solve your issue but I can't stop to ask this, are you sure you can't avoid using so many layouts inside other layouts? Seems like a lot of overdraw

Comment: @MariusBudin Yes, it looks like LinearLayouts are being used instead of ImageViews or ImageButtons.

Comment: @MariusBudin these icon layouts not just a layouts with a bg, i just didn't want to fill the question with unnecessary code, each layout contain a three ImageButtons and a TextView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not going to be able to accomplish this from xml only, you'll need some dynamic code to measure the width of the screen and then programtically set the width of each linearlayout (icon1, icon2 etc) to 1/4 of this width.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels/4, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LinearLayout icon1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.icon1);
icon1.setLayoutParams(params);

//etc
```